# Information about lazy-loading in GWT and GWT-Ext

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

Where can I find more information about GWT and GWT-Ext's lazy loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly googling shows a [nice blog entry](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/11/improving-performance-with-on-demand.html) by the GWT team.

I can't say anything about GWT-Ext, but the same basic techniques will work regardless of technology.

Another possibility for GWT that's coming down for a future release is the "runAsync". Check out the [GWT Web Toolkit Contributors mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit-Contributors), where there are a few different posts on this topic, including [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit-Contributors/browse_thread/thread/eb9c8cf046cbaaf2). Basically, this will let you separate your web app into multiple, independent "sections", and download them on demand.